# MongoDB Java Driver doesn't adhere sslInvalidHostNameAllowed option

Tags: java, mongodb, ssl

The following java code with MongoDB java driver 3.0.4 fails connecting to MongoDB server that is running with `--sslAllowConnectionsWithoutCertificates` option:

```
MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder().sslEnabled(true).sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(true).build();
ServerAddress server = new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017);
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(server, options);

client.getDatabaseNames();
```

The error I get is:

```
    INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:462)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:205)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.sendMessage(CommandHelper.java:89)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:43)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1937)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1478)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:212)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1050)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:735)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:201)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1460)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:145)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 22 more
```

I am trying to use SSL and avoid any certificate validation as I am unable to install any certificate on the client.

Any idea?

Comment: Try to take a look at this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/KB/Unable+to+Connect+to+SSL+Services+due+to+PKIX+Path+Building+Failed)

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of this article. My main concern is if there's anyway to bypass the certificate check as I have no way to control the client certificate store.

Answer (score 0):

Consider building your `MongoClientOptions` with a custom `SSLContext`. The latter one can be build using SSLContextBuilder from **Apache HttpCore**:

```
SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(TrustAllStrategy.INSTANCE)).build();
```

There is also an option to use `TrustSelfSignedStrategy.INSTANCE` or implement your own depending on your setup.